# Is there a log for errors for process that reads the sudoers file?

Tags: sudo, logs

On Ubuntu 14.04 or CentOS: If I'm editing the sudoers file and I make a mistake or something, is there a log file that I can check to see if there are any errors?

Comment: `sudo -l` will tell you pretty quickly! `visudo` is certainly the way to go, though.

Answer (score 5):

Don't edit `/etc/sudoers` directly, this is the job of `visudo`.

`visudo` opens the `sudoers` file e.g. `/etc/sudoers` as `/etc/sudoers.tmp` (lock file) for editing. After you are done with the edit and save the file, it will do sanity check to make sure that everything is syntactically right. After making that sure it will replace the original `sudoers` file e.g. `/etc/sudoers` with the modified `/etc/sudoers.tmp`.

Regarding the log file, i am not aware of one.

As a side note, `visudo` will open `/etc/sudoers` by default, you can pass the `-f` option to open another `sudoers` file e.g.:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/foobar
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but if you use `visudo` to edit, your edits will be validated before they are applied, and you'll be given a chance to fix any (obvious) errors.